# create Sudoku matrix without recursion on machine with limited resources like stack

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, sudoku

I am trying to create a app for watch where i have very limited memory resources and when I am using recursion to generate a Sudoku matrix , I get stack over flow exception. Could some one can give me any inputs if i still want to generate a random Sudoku each time but with limited system resources and no recursion. I am using below code currently which is giving stack over flow exception.

```
package test;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

/**
* The SudokuGenerator class creates a random standard (9x9) Sudoku board
* through the use of backtracking techniques.
*/
public class validS {
public static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 9;
public static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 9;

/**
 * Constructor. Resets board to zeros
 */
public validS() {
    board = new int[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
}

/**
 * Driver method for nextBoard.
 *
 * @param difficult
 *            the number of blank spaces to insert
 * @return board, a partially completed 9x9 Sudoku board
 */
public int[][] nextBoard(int difficulty) {
    board = new int[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
    nextCell(0, 0);
    makeHoles(difficulty);
    return board;

}

/**
 * Recursive method that attempts to place every number in a cell.
 *
 * @param x
 *            x value of the current cell
 * @param y
 *            y value of the current cell
 * @return true if the board completed legally, false if this cell has no
 *         legal solutions.
 */
public boolean nextCell(int x, int y) {
    int nextX = x;
    int nextY = y;
    int[] toCheck = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    Random r = new Random();
    int tmp = 0;
    int current = 0;
    int top = toCheck.length;

    for (int i = top - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        current = r.nextInt(i);
        tmp = toCheck[current];
        toCheck[current] = toCheck[i];
        toCheck[i] = tmp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < toCheck.length; i++) {
        if (legalMove(x, y, toCheck[i])) {
            board[x][y] = toCheck[i];
            if (x == 8) {
                if (y == 8)
                    return true;// We're done! Yay!
                else {
                    nextX = 0;
                    nextY = y + 1;
                }
            } else {
                nextX = x + 1;
            }
            if (nextCell(nextX, nextY))
                return true;
        }
    }
    board[x][y] = 0;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Given a cell's coordinates and a possible number for that cell, determine
 * if that number can be inserted into said cell legally.
 *
 * @param x
 *            x value of cell
 * @param y
 *            y value of cell
 * @param current
 *            The value to check in said cell.
 * @return True if current is legal, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean legalMove(int x, int y, int current) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (current == board[x][i])
            return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (current == board[i][y])
            return false;
    }
    int cornerX = 0;
    int cornerY = 0;
    if (x > 2)
        if (x > 5)
            cornerX = 6;
        else
            cornerX = 3;
    if (y > 2)
        if (y > 5)
            cornerY = 6;
        else
            cornerY = 3;
    for (int i = cornerX; i < 10 && i < cornerX + 3; i++)
        for (int j = cornerY; j < 10 && j < cornerY + 3; j++)
            if (current == board[i][j])
                return false;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Given a completed board, replace a given amount of cells with 0s (to
 * represent blanks)
 *
 * @param holesToMake
 *            How many 0s to put in the board.
 */
public void makeHoles(int holesToMake) {
    /*
     * We define difficulty as follows: Easy: 32+ clues (49 or fewer holes)
     * Medium: 27-31 clues (50-54 holes) Hard: 26 or fewer clues (54+ holes)
     * This is human difficulty, not algorighmically (though there is some
     * correlation)
     */
    double remainingSquares = 81;
    double remainingHoles = (double) holesToMake;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            double holeChance = remainingHoles / remainingSquares;
            if (Math.random() <= holeChance) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
                remainingHoles--;
            }
            remainingSquares--;
        }
}

/**
 * Prints a representation of board on stdout
 */
public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + "  ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    validS sg = new validS();
    sg.nextBoard(70);
    sg.print();
}

int[][] board;
private int operations;
```

}

Comment: Are you sure, your algorithm would run on a normal machine? The recursion depth for a sudoku should not be much larger than 81, I almost can not believe the resources are that scarce..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running out of stack space, because in the "worst" case, i.e. when completing building the board, you've got 81 calls to *nextCell* + 1 to *legalMove*. I'm no a Java person, but the first thing to try is to get rid of the variables at the begining of *nextCall*:

```
int nextX = x;
int nextY = y;

Random r = new Random();
int tmp = 0;
int current = 0;
int top = toCheck.length;
```

-- this *Random* object might be shared between the calls;
if you need to use *nextX*, *nextY* (which you don't actually) try to use them inside the block of *"if (legalMove(x, y, toCheck[i])) {"*;
don't use *top*, just initialize the loop var with *toCheck.length*;
declare *tmp* inside the "shuffling loop".
In geral keeping your variables as local as possible is a good practive not only because of memory management.

If that does not help (which is quite possible) then you can try to use your own control structure -- a stack containing only *x*s, *y*s and *toCheck*s,
trying always the first from the stack, until you run out of *toCheck*s. Here is a sample js implementation (I include the whole thing just so that you can test it e.g. in your browser, but you're only interested in the code for *buildBoard()*):

```
var rand = function(uppBnd) { return(Math.floor(Math.random()*uppBnd)); };
var board = null; /// just for the scoping

function mkEmptyBoard(h,w) { /// can't think of other way to initialize hxw array in js
  var b=[];
  for(i=0;i<h;i++) {
    var r=[];
    for(j=0;j<w;j++) r.push(0);
    b.push(r);
  }
  return b;
}

/// this one is taken from your code, btw you can make this corner things easier.
function legalMove(x,y,current) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (current == board[x][i])
        return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (current == board[i][y])
        return false;
  }
  var cornerX = 0;
  var cornerY = 0;
  if (x > 2)
    if (x > 5)
      cornerX = 6;
    else
      cornerX = 3;
    if (y > 2)
    if (y > 5)
      cornerY = 6;
    else
      cornerY = 3;
  for (var i = cornerX; i < 10 && i < cornerX + 3; i++)
    for (var j = cornerY; j < 10 && j < cornerY + 3; j++)
      if (current == board[i][j])
        return false;
  return true;
}

function nextPos(x,y) { if(x<8) return [x+1,y]; else return [0,y+1]; }

function mkToCheck() { /// this one just builds your "suffled array"
  var toCheck = [];
  for(var i=0;i<9;i++) toCheck.push(i+1);
  for(var i = toCheck.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var tmp;
    current = rand(i);
    tmp = toCheck[current];
    toCheck[current] = toCheck[i];
    toCheck[i] = tmp;
  }
  return toCheck;
}

/// THE THING IS HERE:
function buildBoard() {
  board = mkEmptyBoard(9,9);    
  var stck = [{'x':0,'y':0,'check': mkToCheck()}];    
  while(stck.length>0) {
    while(stck[0].check.length>0) {
      var ch = stck[0].check.shift();
      if(legalMove(stck[0].x, stck[0].y, ch)) {
        board[stck[0].x][stck[0].y] = ch;
        if(stck[0].y==8 && stck[0].x==8) return true; /// yay! board is ready
        var nextpos = nextPos(stck[0].x, stck[0].y);
        stck.unshift({'x':nextpos[0],'y':nextpos[1],'check':mkToCheck()});
        break;
      }
    }
    if(stck[0].check.length==0) { /// a bind alley -- revert!
      board[stck[0].x][stck[0].y]=0;
      stck.shift();
    }
  }
  board=mkEmptyBoard(); // clear the board as this is
  return false; /// a complete failure (hopefully notreached :))
}
```

If that still does not fit your memory, you have to modify your algorithm. Maybe you can make profit of the fact that each row/column is a permutation of a set of positive digits? If you run out of ideas, someone on the stackoverflow (I've seen it somewhere under *sudoku* tag) has suggested another (non-backtracking) method of generating boards, by permuting [groups of] rows and columns of already prepared one (one such pre-computed board is enough to generate ~46k new ones) -- this might be the best thing for your setup.